# how to fix python library management system using for sentence to while sentence?

Tags: python

I want to change for->while code

```
def delete_book(self, book_contents):
    for i in range(0, len(book_contents), 1):
        print(i)
        print(book_contents[i])

    delete_num = int(input("choose the number you want to delete(0=cancel) : "))
    if delete_num == 0:
        print("cancel") 
        return book_contents
    else:
        try:
            self.delete_b(book_contents,delete_num)
        except:
            print("delete fail")
            self.delete_book(book_contents)
        return book_contents
```

I write code like this. but I'm getting the error

```
i=0
while len(book_contents):
    print(book_contents[i])
i+=1
```

can you please help me how to fix it?

Comment: change your while loop condition like this `while i < len(book_contents):` and indent `i += 1` to inside while

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, before asking, extract a [mcve] and provide that along with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to  replace the for loop in your code with a while loop. You can do it like so

```
i = 0
while i < len(book_contents):
    print(book_contents[i])
    i += 1
```

But tbh, for loop would be the better choice as it's shorter

```
for i in range(len(book_contents)):
    print(book_contents[i])
```

i goes from 0 to len(book_contents) - 1 in steps of 1 by default